# cfselenium - how do I implement automation in a coldfusion application

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-2016

Can someone give an idea on how we implement automation using cfselenium. where I can get resources or examples? 
And your feedback will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried getting in touch with the authors via their github page? https://github.com/teamcfadvance/CFSelenium

Comment: nop...am just checking others who tried it and how did they using it.

Comment: If you read the docs: "This version has dropped support for Selenium-RC and Selenium-IDE. Also the tests have been rewritten for TestBox by Ortus Solutions." Given the last update to that repo was 3 years ago, I'd imagine the user base is extremely small. You may be better off reading up on TestBox. https://www.ortussolutions.com/products/testbox

Comment: TestBox is great for BDD testing where you write scripts for automated tests. I haven’t used selenium but I think it’s a lot different in that it allows you to record browser actions that can be automated. It’s a completely different approach.